# Error while clicking next button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in Python and I am trying to Selenium, however, I have a problem with my code, I can not click the next button on pagination. This is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

data = []
page_url = "https://pdb.irb.hr/search?q=&qId=&type=title&limit=2&page=1"
driver.get(page_url)
time.sleep(2)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="searchResultList"]/li[2]/p[1]/a')
for x in range(20):
    for i in range(len(links)):
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="searchResultList"]/li[2]/p[1]/a')[i].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//html/body/div[2]/div/h2").text
        print(title)
        data.append((title))
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[rel="next"]').click()

driver.close()
```

Can somebody tell me what am doing wrong, how to target that next button?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is to scroll the page till the Pagenumbers get visible.

below code is tested working perfectly fine, was able to navigate next 20 pages.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='c:\user1\chromedriver.exe')

data = []
page_url = "https://pdb.irb.hr/search?q=&qId=&type=title&limit=2&page=1"
driver.get(page_url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchResultList"]/li[2]/p[1]/a')
print(len(links))
for x in range(20):
    for i in range(len(links)):
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchResultList"]/li[2]/p[1]/a')[i].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/h2").text
        print(title)
        data.append((title))
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

### below code added to make paginatio visible for selection

```
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[rel="next"]')
    target = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", button)


    next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[rel="next"]')

    next_btn.click()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The next page button is below some other element there so to click on in you have to scroll to it first.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

next_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[rel="next"]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
next_btn.click()
```